# How do I redirect al url request using htaccess when I already have rewrite rules?

Tags: ssl, .htaccess, redirect, https

I've tried everything but simply can't get this to work.

This is the default Wordpress redirect code that sits in my `htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I know I can use:

```
Redirect permanent /login https://mysite.example.com/login
```

But this won't allow me to capture all url's and redirect them.

How would I redirect all incoming urls to https?

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL

Comment: @MichaelHampton So, where should I add this when talking about the above rewrite code `Redirect permanent /login https://mysite.example.com/login`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Please reconsider reopening the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use .htaccess unless you have to. Wordpress has enough security issues without including another + performance slowdown.

That being said, if you're just trying to protect login/admin data you can edit the wp-config.php file to included; `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');` and `define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);`

Also, you can force everything in SSL with the following rewrite rule;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```